# use signal on m2m_changed

Tags: django

Want to use signal when `follow()` function called  in UserProfile. I've written signal which works with other models (on save).

```
class UserProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True,verbose_name=_('user'))
  location = models.CharField(_('Location'), max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
  following = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name=_('following'), related_name='followers', blank=True, null=True)

  def follow(self, user):
    self.following.add(user)

  def unfollow(self, user):
    self.following.remove(user)
```

signal

```
def follow_action(sender, instance, created, action_object=None, **kwargs):
  action.send(instance.user, verb='follows', target=instance.content_object)
post_save.connect(follow_action, sender=UserProfile)
```

this signal works when `UserProfile` model saved. I want to call signal when `follow()`function execute. will you please help? any idea? thanks alot

UPDATE:

```
def follows_action(sender, instance, created, action_object=None, **kwargs):
  action.send(instance.user, verb='follows', target=instance.content_object)
m2m_changed.connect(follows_action, sender=UserProfile.following.through)
```

It does not work. Am i missing something?

Comment: It looks like you are using django-activity-stream (action.send), why use your UserProfile model with follows rather than their Follow model ?

Comment: @jpic You are right. I'm using `django-activity-stream`.

Comment: Probably it doesn't work because the signature of follows_action is wrong, it does not match the excepted m2m_changed callback signature described in the documentation that I linked. I won't lie, it doesn't look like you tried a lot. If you want a nice experience i recommend that you (re)read [hacker howto](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect a callback to a change of a many to many relation, use [m2m_changed signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed).